# Using CreateProcessWithLoginW to elevate setup process in Win7

Tags: windows-7, vb6, createprocessasuser

Am trying to modify a legacy VB6 application to be able to run on Windows 7.  The application runs setup installers for individual sub applications.  Yes, I know that's bad but I can't change that at the moment.

I've been trying to use CreateProcessWithLoginW to elevate the request to run the setup.exe to an admin level account.  This has been working great on a test machine simply using my domain credentials.

However moving it over to another box it fails with a 740 error 'The requested operation required elevation'.  It should be noted I'm using the exact same domain credentials.  I turned UAC off on both machines (I've seen that be a problem for some) but it seems to make no difference.  I also went from profile to net credentials (I had not been loading the profile explicitly on the first try).

The current code I'm using is below.  Any suggestions what might be breaking would be appreciated.

```
lRetCode = CreateProcessWithLogonW(wUser, wDomain, wPassword, _
                LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY, 0&, wCommandLine, _
                CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, 0&, wCurrentDir, startInfo, processInfo)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to break the wall-of-text into some readable paragraphs? As it is now, it's pretty difficult to read. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Well it was my foolishness anyway.  I didn't reboot after turning UAC off.  Doing so solved the problem.